# Septa fibrous in liver histology

Tags: histology, liver, histopathology

I'm scoring liver fibrosis using Laennec scoring system, but i'm so confuse to differentiate between septa fibrous and fibrosis without septa. Anyone can tell me about the characteristic or structure of septa fibrous? Thanks a lot